# Update JSON values with associated key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to collect the unique json data, I mean if the key exists the update its value. But not succeed to update the value of existing key.

```
var fpr_data = [{"rfr_id":"7","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"3","raw_qty":"20.00","raw_wastage":"2","raw_name":"Buttons"}, 
                {"rfr_id":"9","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"4","raw_qty":"500.00","raw_wastage":"0","raw_name":"Yarn"}, 
                {"rfr_id":"8","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"5","raw_qty":"2.00","raw_wastage":"1","raw_name":"Needle"},  
                {"rfr_id":"7","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"3","raw_qty":"20.00","raw_wastage":"2","raw_name":"Buttons"}]; 

var qty = 2, coll={}, _qty=0.00,_wastage=0.00;

// Filter and modify JSON data
$.each(fpr_data, function(i, data) {
    _qty = data.raw_qty * qty;
    _wastage = data.raw_wastage * qty;

    // Next time add on existing keys
    if( coll[data.raw_id] == data.raw_id ) {
        var q = coll[data.raw_id].qty + _qty;
        var w = coll[data.raw_id].wastage + _wastage;

        coll[data.raw_id] = {"qty":q, "wastage":w};
    }
    else {
        coll[data.raw_id] = {"qty":_qty, "wastage":_wastage};
    }
});
console.log(coll);
```

In `fpr_data` there is `raw_id` that i want to collect unique ids and if the raw_id found in object then update its `qty` and `wastage` with `raw_qty` and `raw_wastage`. I got Unique JSON data but quantity and wastage are not getting update. **What wrong i have done?**  You can find the same codes in fiddle and check the result in console.

**Expected:** The value of `qty` in `3` should be `80`

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/danmyzgq/)</kbd>

Comment: Note that what you're manipulating there isn't JSON, it's an array of objects. (It's only JSON when and if it is serialised to a string.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, thanks, to point me in right direction. Can i manipulate it in JSON?

Comment: No, at least not easily since that would be a string manipulation. You can manipulate it directly when you have an array of objects like you do.

Comment: @nnnnnn I am trying check with `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below condition will not give you correct comparison, when object already exists in array.

> if( coll[data.raw_id] == data.raw_id ) {

I think you should just do:

> if(coll[data.raw_id]) {

If I understand you correctly try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/danmyzgq/5/)

```
if(coll[data.raw_id]) {

            var q = coll[data.raw_id].qty + _qty;
            var w = coll[data.raw_id].wastage + _wastage;

            coll[data.raw_id] = {"qty":q, "wastage":w};
        }
        else {
            coll[data.raw_id] = {"qty":_qty, "wastage":_wastage};
        }
```

Comment: Ahh, correct. I was trying to compare object with number.

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery, so enjoy the jQuery.extend() function :

```
var fpr_data = [{"rfr_id":"7","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"3","raw_qty":"20.00","raw_wastage":"2","raw_name":"Buttons"},{"rfr_id":"9","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"4","raw_qty":"500.00","raw_wastage":"0","raw_name":"Yarn"},{"rfr_id":"8","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"5","raw_qty":"2.00","raw_wastage":"1","raw_name":"Needle"}, {"rfr_id":"7","user_id":"5","fp_id":"10","raw_id":"3","raw_qty":"20.00","raw_wastage":"2","raw_name":"Buttons"}];
console.log(fpr_data);
var qty = 2, coll={}, _qty=0.00,_wastage=0.00;

    // Filter and modify JSON data
    $.each(fpr_data, function(i, data) {
        _qty = data.raw_qty * qty;
        _wastage = data.raw_wastage * qty;

        // Next time add on existing keys
        var currentObj = coll[data.raw_id]; // Try not to repeat yourself ;-)
        if( currentObj == data.raw_id ) {
            var q = currentObj.qty + _qty;
            var w = currentObj.wastage + _wastage;
            console.log(data);
            coll[data.raw_id] = $.extend(data, {"qty":q, "wastage":w});
        }
        else {
            coll[data.raw_id] = $.extend(data, {"qty":_qty, "wastage":_wastage});
        }
    });
console.log(coll);
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not what i want.